# Docker container, running PostgreSQL not allowing php's pg_connect from another container

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-network

I have the following architecture:

```
A network with 3 containers:
    container_db, running PostgreSQL
    container_pg_admin, running a simple pgAdmin environment
    container_php_dev, running the whole environment, needed for the application to function properly (nginx, php, angular for the frontend, etc.)
```

When I try to pg_connect() from container_php_dev to container_db the connection gets refused. This is the actual error message I get: `pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: could not connect to server: No route to host↵    Is the server running on host "container_db" (172.18.0.4) and accepting↵    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?`.

However, when I try to connect to `container_db` from `container_pg_admin` I face no problem achieving this (host is `container_db` and port is 5432). Even if I map port 5432 of `container_db` to 5555 on host, I'm able to connect to 127.0.0.1:5555 from DBeaver or other DB Manager (TeamSQL).

All containers were restarted a few times as well as docker itself. And as this is my development machine, the host PC was restarted as well.

What might be the problem, how to diagnose and possibly solve? Have any of you experienced such strange docker behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Try running the `container_db` in the hosted network using flag `--network host`

Comment: I get an error message: `Container cannot be connected to host network or disconnected from host network`. Yet, I don't think this is needed, as I have a problem with the docker network which will be run on a separate machine when in production. Host network is not an option.

Comment: I built the image from ground up and it runs normally now. Sorry, that I cannot provide a valuable solution.